# Efficiently query comments of all posts at a controller level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, rails-activerecord

I have an index action in posts controller, and the view displays all posts with their comments following each post. My current implementation is, in the embedded html file, in the block of `@posts.each do |p|` I'm using `p.comments` to get all comments of each post. However, it seems not good to do this just in the view, but I can't find a way of doing that in controller. Can anyone give some suggestions? Or is this just the correct way to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you controller, when you query posts, use `includes(:comments)` to reduce the number of SQL query from 1+n to 2:

```
@posts = Post.includes(:comments).where(......)
```

You can leave the code in your view as it is, `p.comments` won't fire more SQL queries.

Check the tutorial [Eager loading associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations).

Comment: and how do I access these comments in the view??

Comment: @OneZero you can leave your view code as it is, Rails won't fire new SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Arie is spot on with solving the n + 1 problem. In terms of the view, you can still use the same approach, but it would be better to use collection partials:

```
# posts/index.html.erb
<%= render @posts %>
```

This will look for a partial located at `/views/posts/_post.html.erb` as send it a `post` variable. It will do this for every Post model in the `@posts` array.

For the comments, in `_post.html.erb` you could write:

```
# /views/posts/_post.html.erb
<% # Post content here %>
<%= render post.comments %>
```

Which like the posts collection, will render each comment using the partial located at `/views/comments/_comment.html.erb`

For more details, check out the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)